# How to throw a custom AccessDeniedException in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security. When `AccessDeniedException` happens, I would like to show the reason why the access was denied in the response.

For example, I would like to show something like "you can't delete the object because you are not the owner" or "you can't create new objects because your account has been suspended". I expect that such messages are propagated with a custom `AccessDeniedException`, e.g. `NotOwnerException` or `AccountSuspendedException`.

I am trying `@PreAuthorize` annotations with a custom `PermissionEvaluator`, but it seems that there is no way to propagate such reasons from my `PermissionEvaluator` to the response.

Is there any way to achieve this in Spring Security? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Spring Security doesn't suggest or even allow us to throw a custom `AccessDeniedException`.

According to the discussion in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/1425), Luke Taylor (the maintainer of Spring Security) said:

> AccessDeniedHandler is normally only called when an authenticated user attempts to access something they should not. The normal flow of the application should prevent them from doing this, so it should only happen if they are deliberately manipulating URLs (or something) in order to try to circumvent their normal boundaries or if there is a bug in the application.

Since "access denied" should not happen in a normal flow, the exception doesn't have to be customizable.